# Opcache with Joomla! and Resolved Name

Tags: php, caching, joomla, opcache

I have been researching the best use of OPcache with Joomla.

This github page, [The Zend Engine and OPcode caching](https://github.com/TerryE/opcache/wiki/The-Zend-Engine-and-opcode-caching#wiki-Opcode_caching_with_OPcache), is the best explanation of how OPcache works that I've seen and was trying to get answers to a couple of points here.

**Resolved filename**:

- What does "Resolved filename" mean?
- What does Opache use as the "Resolved filename" since I use Joomla! CMS and I know that it always call the index.php but passes different parameters is the resolved file name index.php?[querystring]

**Timestamp Used**:

- How does "timestamp" apply with a CMS/Framework system such as Joomla! because since the index.php file never changes it seems to me that the cache would never refresh.

**Joomla! CMS Caching system**:

- Does it makes sense to use the cache in Joomla? It writes the pages it builds out to the file system in the folder named "cache" as php files and those php pages will be called instead of Joomla rebuilding the pages every time

Comment: The poster asked this Q off-list, but I felt that the Q&A would be of value SO community, so I suggested that we expose it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resolved Filenames

The PHP equivalent of a resolved filename is obtained by the [realpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function.  This converts all symbolic links, any  references to '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the input path, against the current working directory in the case of a relative filename returning the canonicalized absolute pathname. In other words the resolved filename is a complete filename mapping onto the underlying filesystem.  It's not necessarily unique, because of hard links, etc..

**OPcache** uses the resolved filename as the index into its internal compiled script database for two reasons:

- Having relative filenames and embedded symlinks opens all sorts of security and simple application programming beartraps that can cause bugs or enable exploitable vulnerabilities.  By using the resolved filename for each script as its key, OPcache avoids these issues.
- This also can have material performance benefits with multi installations of packages like phpBB, WordPress, MediaWiki (and I assume Joomla) which typically use a hierarchical PHP directory structure.  You can symlink many versions of a common subdirectory onto a shared library folder, and this way separate logical instances of a package can share the same compiled script in the OPcache internal database.

The *query parameters* are quite separate from a script being executed.  The parameters typically vary from request to request depending on the request context but the executed script is the same, and ditto any *included* scripts for the same processing path.

### Script Timestamps

The timestamp of each underlying script file is used by OPcache as a secondary key.  This is to enable detection of changes to the underlying script which will normally result in a changed timestamp.  There are various [opcache INI parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php) which can be used to reduce the performance hit as well as OPcache API calls (such as [opcache_invalidate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-invalidate.php)) which can enable sysadmins to do this explicitly.

Since the (standard) OPcache internal cache is entirely in-memory, it does not have a persistent version on, say, the filesystem.  Hence it must be rebuild every time the underlying PHP process hierarchy (which is typically web-server specific) is reloaded.  And yes, this does result in a startup performance hit whilst the cache is re-primed.

This use of timestamps is to do with the caching of script compilations and quite separate to any application content related caching

### Application Caching

What OPcache does is to avoid per-request the compilation costs.  For any PHP application based on a framework or a complex package such as Joomla or MediaWiki this can represent typically 50-90% of the per-request CPU cost, hence leading to a 2-10X throughput improvement.

Application caching is application-specific and relate to avoiding per-request costs of execution applications code for duplicated processing of application data.

These are quite separate and to get good application performance, you always should consider doing both.